# How to delete JSON Element in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object key element that i want to delete.
Lets say i want to delete the element of everything inside 'v8fe3m'

I tried using unset and delete. Nothing seems work unless my syntax is wrong.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "587ye4": {
      "name": "abc",
      "ip": "zz",
      "loc": "azz"
    },
    "v8fe3m": {
      "name": "japan",
      "ip": "aaa",
      "loc": "123",
      "backups": {
        "HELLO_1595524710053": {
          "ts": 1595524710053,
          "name": "HELLO",
          "size": 770641
        },
        "HELLO_1595524717330": {
          "ts": 1595524717330,
          "name": "HELLO",
          "size": 770641
        },
        "HELLO_1595524717558": {
          "ts": 1595524717558,
          "name": "HELLO",
          "size": 770698
        }
      }
    },
    "x0190a": {
      "name": "dubai",
      "ip": "101",
      "loc": "UAE"
    }
  }
}
```

```
$user_token = $_SESSION["userToken"];
$user_projects_json = read_json($GLOBALS['URL_JSON'] . "$user_token" . "_projects" .".json");
$projectKey = $_REQUEST['dataKey'];
$projectKey = trim($projectKey," ");
//v8fe3m
    $backups = $user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey];
    
    unset($backups);
```

Comment: please show your code/attempt

Comment: https://3v4l.org/46n98 - your welcome

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i edited mine. oh wow thank you too

Comment: in your case it would be `unset($user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey])`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you, by right it should work...but it just doesn't. i check my json file its permission is 777 as well..

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is a strange language, it copies objects. Therefore `$backups` is a copy of `$user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey]`.

```
$backups = $user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey];
unset($backups); //You are unsetting a very new object.
```

You can do

```
$backups = &$user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey];
unset($backups); //You are unsetting a reference that refers to your object.
```

This way `$backups` are referring to your original object, thus unsetting what you need. I saw someone did it in the comments, but there were no explanation, unsetting without creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

First use `$arrayFromJson = json_decode($yourJsonObject, true);`, then you can use standard PHP array functions such as:

```php
unset($arrayFromJson['v8fe3m']);
```